# Is there a way to get the ECharts series symbol to be passed in as the marker in the tooltip

Tags: echarts

I've got an ECharts chart that has multiple line series and a scatter series that represents events. For the line series, we left the symbol at the default, but for the event scatter series we set the symbol to 'diamond'. These symbols show up on the chart & in the series legend as expected. However, the tooltip always shows a 10 pixel dot for the marker. The color however is picked up from the series (and even from the visualMap config!). My initial assumption had been that the symbol would also be picked up from the series. In our case we wanted to use a function for tooltip.formatter and even in that function we couldn't figure out how to access and swap in the series symbol for the marker. We ended up working around it by just custom styling our own html to plug in for the marker that matched the diamond symbol pretty well.

So the open questions are:

1. Is there a way to have the tooltip marker pick up the symbol from the series?
2. If not, is this a bug? I'm happy to put in an issue on the project but I don't want to do that until I understand a bit more.

Here's some code to illustrate what we had to do to get the diamond in there in case it helps the discussion or if others want to leverage this workaround:

```
    formatTooltip(args){      
      let time = DateTime.fromISO(args[0].data[0], { zone: this.user.timeZone }) 
      let tooltip = `<div><b>${time.toFormat(TOOLTIP_FORMAT)}</b></div>`

      args.forEach(({ marker, seriesName, value }) => {
        if (seriesName === 'Events'){
          let myMarker = `<span style="display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:10px;height:10px;background:${value[4]};transform:rotate(45deg);"></span>`
          tooltip += `<div>${myMarker} ${value[3] ? value[3]: ''}</div>`
        } else {
          value = value || [0, 0]
          tooltip += `<div>${marker} ${seriesName}: ${value[1]}</div>`
        }
      })
      return tooltip
    },
```

Comment: Hi Paul, indeed, I think we can consider that as a bug (or at least, an inconsistency).

Comment: I found this existing open issue and added comments to it: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/18016. It seems to be the same as what I'm describing.